# ASP .Net MVC + IIS 7.5 + Static field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have ASP .Net MVC project with additional MFC Service running in it (.svc file included in project, not separate project). I name it Concentrator. It have static field bookDays that is being set from DB in static constructor. It's being used in GetSlots method of Concentrator. Here is code (I have removed everything unrelated)

```
class Concentrator : IConcentrator
{
    private static int bookDays = 0;
    public static int BookDays {
        get { return bookDays; }
        set { bookDays = value; }
    }
    static RegConcentratorGeneral()
    {
        var settings = //DB query was here
        if (settings != null)
            BookDays = settings.BookDays;
    }
    public getSlotsResponse getSlots(getSlotsRequest request)
    {
        DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(BookDays);
    }
}
```

I have also settings-saving Controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(ConcentratorSettings ConcentratorParams)
{
    //Saving settings in DB removed
    RegConcentrator.BookDays = ConcentratorParams.BookDays;
}
```

That was working on my PC, on test IIS server, but fails on production. getSlots simply uses old value of BookDays that being set in constructor. Seems like it doesn't change when I setting it using controller. There is no exception, Save() method ever saves settings in DB, but getSlots produces results based on prevevious value anyway. When I have replaced using BookDays by DB query in getSlots(), problem have disappeared. What could be the reason of that? Production server isn't cluster.

Comment: It's not very clear. Do you expect your service to use new value as soon as you update it using your MVC Controller?

Comment: iss can suspend app while there is no any request. static variables and all released. it starts app after first request.

Comment: Andrei M
Yes, of course.
Nuri YILMAZ
Hmm. But if app is suspended and started again, shouldn't static constructor be executed again as well? If it is, it should retrieve settings from DB, not use some random old value.

Comment: @AndreiM no. static ctor will work again when any client access member of this class. you should save state by effective persist method. forexample could you use db to store this state?

Comment: @Nuri YILMAZ Setting is being saved to the DB when Save() method is called. So DB value is always up-to-date. Taking value from DB every time getSlots() is called works good, but it's slow and I was trying to avoid that using static field.

Comment: @DanilEroshenko it is ok now? may be you should check cache assid pattern. it is useful cache and save state. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589799.aspx